# Customize current Visual Studio Code theme

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I'm making changes to the current theme (Atom theme) such that strings in all languages or at least python and javascript show up in a particular color.

In settings.json, I have added the below but it doesn't seem to reflect.

```
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Atom One Light]": {
            "enabled": true,
            "rules": {
                "string": { "color": "#FFFFFF" }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following in your `settings.json`:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "[Atom One Light]": { "strings": "#FF0000"},
}
```

[image: python screenshot]

Comment: What is semanticTokenColorCustomizations for?

Comment: I was trying the above but as `string` 

Comment: Sorry I'm not too sure the difference between `semanticTokenColorCustomizations` and `tokenColorCustomizations`... I think this can be a new Stack Overflow question :)

Comment: @John Semantic-Tokens are tokens that target specific language semantics. The semantics are defined by a language server. If your language supports semantics, which IDK if python does, but I do know that the primary language I write, TypeScript, does indeed support them. When I enable the semantic tokens I am able to set somatic tokens in my theme so that my editor knows certain things, like when a variable was declared as a parameter, or when a variable is an instance of a class. This is useful as heck, because the highlighting is far more consistent, and often makes more sense.